# How to include tax in minimum order amount magento

Tags: magento

on a french ecommerce, we always display prices including taxes.

I have enabled the minimum order amount.

I've test it, it works but the system is based on subtotal excluding taxes.
I need the system based for the this case on global amount (including taxes)
Is it possible ?

Of course I tried to work with a minimum amount excluding taxes, but I manage two tax rates. So It can't be good.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible:

1. Copy file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php`
2. Open copied file and find validateMinimumAmount() function:

   ```
   public function validateMinimumAmount($multishipping = false) {

   $storeId = $this->getStoreId();

   $minOrderActive = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/active', $storeId);

   $minOrderMulti  = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/multi_address', $storeId);

   $minAmount  = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);


   if (!$minOrderActive) {
       return true;
   }

   $addresses = $this->getAllAddresses();

   if ($multishipping) {
       if ($minOrderMulti) {
           foreach ($addresses as $address) {
               foreach ($address->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
                   $amount = $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount();
                   if ($amount < $minAmount) {
                       return false;
                   }
               }
           }
       } else {
           $baseTotal = 0;
           foreach ($addresses as $address) {
               /* @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
               $baseTotal += $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount();
           }
           if ($baseTotal < $minAmount) {
               return false;
           }
       }
   } else {
       foreach ($addresses as $address) {
           /* @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
           if (!$address->validateMinimumAmount()) {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   return true;
   ```

   }
3. Replace this function with next:

   ```
   public function validateMinimumAmount($multishipping = false)
   {

       $storeId = $this->getStoreId();

       $minOrderActive = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/active', $storeId);

       $minOrderMulti  = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/multi_address', $storeId);

       $minAmount      = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);


   if (!$minOrderActive) {
       return true;
   }

   $addresses = $this->getAllAddresses();

   if ($multishipping) {
       if ($minOrderMulti) {
           foreach ($addresses as $address) {
               $grandTotal = $address->getQuote()->collectTotals()->getGrandTotal();
               if ($grandTotal < $minAmount) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       } else {
           $grandTotal = 0;
           foreach ($addresses as $address) {
               /* @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
               $grandTotal += $address->getQuote()->collectTotals()->getGrandTotal();
           }
           if ($grandTotal < $minAmount) {
               return false;
           }
       }
   } else {
       foreach ($addresses as $address) {
           /* @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
           $grandTotal = $address->getQuote()->collectTotals()->getGrandTotal();
           if ($grandTotal < $minAmount) {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   return true;
   }
   ```
4. Clear Magento Cache (`System->Configuration->Cache Management`).

In new function we use many collectTotals() calls for be sure what Grand Total already calculated but don't worry about calculations overhead because collectTotals() function contains protect from double totals calculation:

```
if ($this->getTotalsCollectedFlag()) {
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to bring problems with PayPal. "Quote totals must be collected before this operation".

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the model `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` and override the method `validateMinimumAmount`:

```
<?php

class StackExchange_MinimumOrderValue_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
{

    /**
     * Validate minimum amount
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateMinimumAmount()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getQuote()->getStoreId();
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/active', $storeId)) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() && $this->getAddressType() == self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return true;
        } elseif (!$this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() && $this->getAddressType() != self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return true;
        }

        $amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
        // $this->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() is sometimes null, so that we calculate it ourselves
        $referenceAmount = $this->getBaseSubtotal() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount() + $this->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount() - $this->getBaseShippingTaxAmount() - abs($this->getBaseDiscountAmount());
        if ($referenceAmount < $amount) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The interesting thing is that `$this->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()` does not work. It is sometimes `null` - specifically, if you proceed from the cart to the checkout page. Hence, we calculate the subtotal inclusive tax ourselves. I hope my formula is correct, but it seems to work:

```
$referenceAmount = $this->getBaseSubtotal() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount() + $this->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount() - $this->getBaseShippingTaxAmount() - abs($this->getBaseDiscountAmount());
```